# Git Reset after multiple bad rebasing after push

Tags: git, push, rebase, history

I'm new here so I'll try to do my best.

I have some troubles with a my git branch.

Indeed I am developing on a branch called let's say 'myName'. I am working on a new feature that is taking a long time developing. That's why I regularly did 'git rebase master'. However, I pushed my commits before I did the rebasing.

So my branch and the remote branch has diverged. I pull the changes and then continue developping. After 2 or 3 times I realized that it kind of destroys my git history. So I wanted to know how can I do either to clean my history, or to get the code of this branch on a new branch that would be a new start, without keeping this bad history.

Here is a preview of my history:

```
1af3418 (HEAD -> dashboards) Add of the mapChart & new start
a18d6b9 Add of the mapChart with real Data
cd29620 Adaptation of the LineChart component and the Dashboards page after setting the backend
71d288e Add of LineCharts Components and display of 1st LineChart component with Fake Data
ca33ac3 WA-446 Check undefined oauth
d4124bb Add of the PieChart Component 1st charts on Dashboards page
83db3e8 Test of rebase command
f474a41 Test of rebase command
3c3d0a4 Fix undefined ClipLoader
1297024 Update react to 16.8.3
ad83624 Test of rebase command
8f145a3 Test of rebase command
ec363bf Test to add dahsboard page
bc71ead Fix undefined ClipLoader
40cc4ff Update react to 16.8.3
```

Tell me if you need more information and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use the `git reset --soft hash_you_want_to_replace` or `git reset --mixed hash_you_want_to_replace` (the default) and do a new commit.

You will create a new commit at the hash you picked with the last changes of your working directory and you will erase the commits after the one you pick (get a backup first to be sure)

So with `git reset ec363bf` you will to replace the `Test to add dahsboard page` and delete all the other commits until the HEAD

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Okay, with this solution I lose the logic history of my branch. 
However I didn't find a better solution and it allows me to have a clean history. So, unless someone has a magical proposition I will take yours. 

Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure what you really want to do. If you want to delete all the commits and the log history delete the `.git ` folder and start over with a `git init`.